# OrbitControls still rotate on model origin even when pan?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I will explain my question by image:

### Here is the view of top camera, the gray cube is 3d model, 'X' mean the 'centre of rotation', arrow means direction of rotate:

[image]

### Normally, when we pan, the 'centre of rotation' still at center of camera so direction of rotate look like this:

[image]

### The question is:

### How can i make the 'centre of rotation' at center of 3d model even when i pan like below:

[image]

Thank you very much, please ask if you don't understand my question (apologize for my english).

Comment: You will have to rewrite `OrbitControls` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to translate your model back to origin, process the rotation, and translate it back to it's last position. so your rotation matrix will include 2 more transformations

```
rotation = TranslateBack * Rotate * TranslateForth
```

[image]

Comment: where are those variables?